# Excel data connections ghost behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook with data connections to a number of TXT files containing data. I had to change the source file on one of them which all worked fine. However when I did a “refresh all” the data from the original TXT file came through. When I refreshed just that file the new data came through. I checked the connection list there was only one and it was pointing to the old file but when I looked in the names there were two overlapping names ranges.  I deleted one and that fixed the problem.

I’ve never seen this ghost problem before. Is there any reason for concern?

Comment: Did you connect TXT files with Power Query, or for what reason?

Comment: Just used the standard data connection tool in the ribbon. The reason is I’m looking at some data exported from our accounting system and it does things in tab or comma separated text files

Comment: What accounting software you are currently using?

Comment: MYOB AccountRight self hosted.  (Won’t be for much longer)

Comment: MY suggestion is, better you talk to the system designer coz,, your activities are MYOB dependant,, as you have written also,"I’m looking at some data exported from our accounting system ".